# React TypeScript Error. onCreate! No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<{}>): gave the following error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when it on Javascript, it work. but on typeScript, say it error. why?
how can i do?

App.tsx

```
class App extends React.Component<{}, null> {
    handleCreate = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <PhoneForm **onCreate**={this.handleCreate}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

that case, render()'s onCreate has next error :

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly<{}>): PhoneForm', gave the following error.     Type '{ onCreate: (data: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PhoneForm> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.       Property 'onCreate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PhoneForm> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: {}, context?: any): PhoneForm', gave the following error.     Type '{ onCreate: (data: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PhoneForm> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.       Property 'onCreate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<PhoneForm> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

PhoneForm.tsx

```
class PhoneForm extends Component {
    state = {
        memberName: '',
        phone: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.**onCreate**(this.state);
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            phone: ''
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    placeholder="Member's Name"
                    value={this.state.memberName}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="memberName"
                />
                <input
                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                    value={this.state.phone}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="phone"
                />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

and on PhoneForm.tsx has next error :

```
TS2339: Property 'onCreate' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

how can i set type to onCreate?
(i'm not want resolve by ts-lint @ts-ignore. i want to know how to set type to onCreate!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with TypeScript and React, you will need to define an interface or type alias for your class components props and state:

```
interface PhoneFormState {
  memberName: string;
  phone: string;
}

interface PhoneFormProps {
  onCreate: (formState: PhoneFormState) => void;
}
```

And then, you will use the interfaces are part of React.Component's type generic parameters:

```
class PhoneForm extends Component<PhoneFormProps, PhoneFormState> {
```

Comment: thanks your comment! it's very helpful!. i applied it. but it have other problem....
```
handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

Comment: that said : TS2345: Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PhoneFormState | ((prevState: Readonly<PhoneFormState>, props: Readonly<PhoneFormProps>) => PhoneFormState | Pick<...>) | Pick<...>'.   Type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<PhoneFormState, "memberName" | "phone">': memberName, phone

sorry but... do you have any idea?

Comment: i did try type convert like this(type convert like java or etc...) : ``` [e.target.name]: (string) e.target.value ``` but it's not work on typescript

Comment: Hmm.. it seems like it is not recognising `e.target.name` as ` memberName` or `phone `